# Laravel saml2 metadata encryption block

Tags: laravel, saml-2.0

I can't understand, how to generate `<md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">`
for the metadata file block in the Laravel application. The app uses **aacotroneo/laravel-saml2** and  **onelogin/php-saml** packages. In settings I tried to set `'wantNameIdEncrypted' => true` and/or `'wantAssertionsEncrypted' => true.` But in the /saml2/idpName/metadata I see only `<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">`.  Maybe it is because I am on the local environment?
I am stuck with this problem for many hours and will be grateful for any explanation about how this blocks are generated and how to use both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I just didn't add 'security' key to the mentioned parameters. They were in the end of example file without any keys and I thought, that it is enough to just uncomment right lines, but no, they are a part of security config.